# Why does Stack Overflow use STV for its elections? Would another system be considered?

Tags: discussion, moderator-election

Apparently, all Stack Exchange sites use *Single Transferrable Voting*, with *Meek* quotas, using OpenSTV software. This is not a terrible choice, but I believe there are better ones.

What would it take for another election system to be considered? This could be in terms of the software support, theoretical underpinnings, empirical track record, demonstrated community interest, and/or other factors, that a rival system would have to attain in order to compete with the current choice.

Comment: Because Jeff Atwood liked it.  And nobody disliked it.  You can apply for a job [here](http://stackexchange.com/work-here).

Comment: @Hans, each intervention of yours is a reader's delight :))

Comment: If you think that there are better choices, you should just make a well-reasoned argument in favor of one of the alternatives. Present it here, in quasi-question form, with the [meta-tag:feature-request] tag. Your argument will have to be good enough to outweigh the fact that STV is the current choice and it is working.

Answer (score 12):

Simply [make your point for it on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?title=Please%20use%20the%20XXX%20system%20for%20moderator%20elections&tags=feature-request%20election) and explain why it would be a better fit for the system. I tried to make a somewhat similar plea [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/102239/13992) and, while running the numbers on actual election data isn't necessary, it helps, and while it didn't help me *enough*, it might tip the odds in your favour.

Take historical election results from the SE elections and run the numbers again both ways:  are the results different? Why are those differences for the better? etc.